# When scrolling chart then cursor is also moving with chart

Tags: c#, teechart

I am using teechart. I have plotted cursor on chart. When I am scrolling or zooming the chart then cursor is also moved along with chart.

I want to stop moving of cursor when scrolling/zooming the chart. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What a weird requirement. From a user-perspective losing the position just because you scroll sounds like a really bad idea. You will have to know the relative position and restore it after the scroll..

Comment: I tried that approach but cursor is fluctuating from its position while scrolling the chart.